# Find List Creator using PnP

Tags: list, pnp-powershell

I would like to identify the creator of a list with PowerShell PnP. AFAIK, I need to read the `Author` property, but the best I've found is the GUID of the author.

```
> $l = Get-PnPList -Identity <the list> -Includes Fields
> $l.Fields | Where-Object InternalName -eq Author

Title    InternalName Id
-----    ------------ --
Créé par Author       1xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I cannot get the user from these information. If there's a better way anyway, please, mention it!

Comment: Are you looking for the creator of the List, or of each item within the list?  The `Author` field stores the creator of each item in the List, not of the list itself.

Comment: I didn't know that `Author` field stores the creator of the items. I'm on the wrong track! I'm trying to get the creator of the list indeed (I'm the creator of the site collection).

Comment: I had found this link on MSDN for SP-2010 [how-to-know-who-created-the-list-in-sharepoint-site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/f4bcd264-844e-414f-93b3-6f994ef48d34/how-to-know-who-created-the-list-in-sharepoint-site?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy). `Author` is mentioned as list creator:  `SPList.Author Property gives you an SPUser object that represents information about the user who created the list.`. I'm looking for SP-2013+ preferably with PnP.

Comment: You cannot get that value through PnP, you'll have to run code on the server to use SPList.

Comment: You can get the user who created the list using PowerShell. check [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/find-who-created-list-library-in-sharepoint-powershell.html). I know this is not PnP-PowerShell but you can give it try. if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @Ganesh I had seen your link [www.sharepointdiary.com](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/find-who-created-list-library-in-sharepoint-powershell.html), but thought it could be feasible in PnP. I don't know if `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` worked out (not error output). I'm not familiar with PSSnapin, but `Get-SPWeb` is not recognized.

Comment: I think there is no straight forward way to get this details using PnP-PowerShell.

Comment: I understand. But as I'm not the SharePoint admin, only a site collection admin, I don't have access to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell`, hence no solution I guess. Thanks.

Comment: to use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` it has to be executed server-side -- meaning you will need to open a remote desktop session to, or be physically present on the server to execute those commands.  SPO-PowerShell, PnP-PowerShell, REST, and CSOM all have the advantage that they can make remote connections from your machine To SharePoint, but they do not support all the capabilities of server-side code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Conclusion: no way to get List Creator client-side!

Comment: Don't give up yet -- I think I may have found a way, let me test out my theory...

Comment: For anyone following this comment thread:  while the list creator is not available in the client-side object model, it is in the list's `SchemaXml` property, and that property **can** be accessed through the client-side object model.  Detailed answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the `List` object exposed by CSOM and Pnp-PowerShell does not *Directly* contain the same `Author` property that the server-side object contains -- However, this value **Is** still in the underlying XML schema of the list.  The schema is not returned by default when you call `get-pnpList`, but it can be included with the `Includes`, parameter, and then it is just a matter of parsing the `Author` attribute from the XML, which is very easy to do in PowerShell.

Give this a try:

```
$l = Get-PnPList -Identity <the list> -includes "SchemaXml"
$listSchema = [xml]$l.SchemaXml
$listCreatorUserId = $listschema.list.author
$listCreatorUser = get-pnpUser $listCreatorUserId
```

Comment: Bravo! it worked out perfectly. Thanks a lot.