# How to extract List Creator using Pnp PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, office-365-developer

I'd like to extract the list metadata for SPO site Collection including the list creator using PnP PowerShell.

Can anyone help how to get it? Referred the below link but not working.

[Find List Creator using PnP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277026/find-list-creator-using-pnp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity 'ListName'
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $list -Property Author
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
#Connect to site
$SiteUrl = "https://test.spo.com/sites/echo"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -UseWebLogin
#connect to list
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity Test
#Get list information
Write-host "List Title:"$List.Title -ForegroundColor Green
Write-host "List Author:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $List -Property Author
```

[image]